# C++ - Code compiles in Debug but not in Release

Tags: c++, compilation

I have some code that compiled without an error in debug mode but when I tried to compile in release code, this is what I have:

2>someSolution.lib(someClass.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
2>fatal error C1047: The object or library file '..\release\someSolution.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries

I have tried to use Clean Solution and Rebuild solution without any luck. I have even tried to delete the .lib file in Windows to force it to be rebuilt.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Which IDE are you using? You did not specify.

Comment: Sorry I am using VS2008 Professional on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I will need to get the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed. Thanks for everyone else who helped in this question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is Visual Studio? This error looks like you are mixing different toolset versions within the projects of your solution. It probably doesn't happen in debug mode because that doesn't use the /LTCG (Link-time Code Generation) option.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, please verify that the options set in 
Project > *right click* > Preferences > Linker (especially check the dynamic libraries paths and dependencies) are the same in release mode with those in debug and that you have not forgotten to include anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Studio Proj Configuration, you have to pay attention that the debug config and release have the right linked library AND additional headers directories.